# WPF(MVVM) + Entity Framework: сохранение данных через OnPropertyChange

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

Хорошей ли практикой считается использовать такой способ сохранения изменений? Или всё же лучше оформлять всё через события для каждого места где происходит изменение? Контекст приложения таков, что в довольно большом количестве мест можно свободно менять данные и при этом желательно видеть изменения в тот же момент. (Приложение тренировочное\для личного пользования).

```
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
    {
        using (ApplicationContext db = new ApplicationContext())
        {
            db.Update(this);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
```

Comment: а что хорошего в этом коде? В смысле, какие вы видите плюсы здесь? У вас на каждый чих надо лазать в БД? У вас нет разделения между моделью и доступом к данным? Вам не надо контроллировать создание контекста данных? Вы пишете в БД и сразу вызываете событие? То есть если запись в БД фейлится, ваши события не вызваются и просто всё падает?

Comment: Ну вот дело то в том что как раз на каждый чик лазить и надо т.к. подразумевается запуск сразу 2-х приложений,  подключённых к одной БД где в одном приложении данные меняются, а в другом уже происходят вычисления и как-то лень было писать обработчики(просто играюсь с новой для себя технологией, ни с чем серьёзным не связано). И вот решил спросить про уместность подобного способа изменений хоть где-то. Ну да ладно, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: если у вас 2 клиента и какой то сервер БД, то логичней делать серверную часть в виде сервиса, а не просто прокидывать доступ к голой базе. Тогда можно и клиентов об изменении оповещать. Хотя, у разных БД есть ещё свои мезанизмы обратной связи в том числе.

Comment: по поводу лени: чем лучше вы подумаете в начале вашего проекта, тем меньше вы аремени потратите на его переписывание.

Comment: Это не серверное приложение, БД локальная. Да и чего тут продумывать, мне просто пришла в голову идея, вот я за пару часов и накидал прототип просто чтобы посмотреть будет ли вообще работать. К слову, работает.

Comment: Если у вас 2 приложения и оба локальные, то вы можете их связать через любой из способов кросс-процессного взаимодействия. Ну или раз работает, то и ладно =)

Comment: У вас вопрос в чем? `Хорошей ли практикой считается` или `Работает это или нет?` я чет не пойму. Если первое, то вам выше сказали, это очень плохой подход по многим причинам, одна из основных - вы на каждое изменение открываете запрос к базе и шлете туда данные. Вот допустим у вас есть класс "сотрудник", вы все сделали, все хорошо и тут человек меняет ему имя (1 запрос), меняет фамилию (2-й запрос), потом зарплату (3-й запрос), потом увидел опечатку в имени (4-й запрос) и вот уже минимум 4 запроса шлется в базу от одного клиента, чтоб изменить 1 объект в базе. А представьте если клиентов 1000.

Comment: Также это, по сути, нарушение MVVM, ибо работа с базой - это модель, а она у вас, по сути, в VM слое. Так что, "хороший код" - однозначно нет, такое расточительство ресурсов — это ужас как плохо. Хотите на каждый чих менять данные на сервере, ну тогда используйте созданные для этого вещи, соккет соединения всякие, SignalR и прочее, которые позволяют в реальном времени общаться клиенту и серверу. Ну а так, "если работает", то смысл тогда от этого вопроса, если вы для себя уже все сами решили?